# Converting Matlab cell into np array

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have a .mat file, with only the following data inside :
cell{Name,Matrix(1610x10)} and I would like to obtain the matrix data in a numpy array to process it.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matlab data file to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197449/matlab-data-file-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Have you tried the `scipy.io.loadmat` function?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the data as CSV and read the data with python.
After this transform it to a numpy array.

http://www.mikesoltys.com/2014/04/06/readingwriting-to-csv-in-matlab/

in python:

```
csvData = []
with open("DATA.csv") as data:
    csv_reader_objekt = csv.reader(data)
    for row in csv_reader_objekt:
        csvData.append(row)

DataArray = np.array(csvData)
```

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is that I have a vast amount of files to convert to CSV. My problem was, once I have loaded the document, and accessed to the cell, how can I obtain the data matrix?

Comment: I have tried this:                                                                                                           from scipy.io import loadmat
arr = np.arange(1601*10).reshape(1601,10)  
annots = loadmat('examp.mat')                                                                                                 But then, I still don´t know how to obtain the matrix

Comment: If you use `np.reshape` you should have a data matrix already. Ah `loadmat` i remember using this in my first semester. You can try to print out the shape of the matrix to check it `print(arr.shape)`