# Extract data using Pandas library from Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have 32 MATLAB files(ex:"s01.mat") which contains data from 32 subjects from an experiment. Every file is structured like this: 40 x 40 x 8064(video x channel x data(128Hzx63s).

For each subject I should extract data for all 40 videos, just for a few channels(sensors)('GSR', 'Temp', 'Resp') and I should create dataframes with pandas library from Python.

How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197449/matlab-data-file-to-pandas-dataframe

Have you already stumbled across this?

Comment: I studied those approaches, but they do not fit my purpose. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @MD98, I discovered that the best solution for my  problem would be pandas.MultiIndex...do you have any experience with this? :)