# Read Matlab file in Python and convert to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matlab

I tried to import Matlab file into python and form a dataframe.

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
import os.path
path=os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())+"/BatteryDataSet/BatteryAgingARC_25_26_27_28_P1/B0025.mat"
mat = loadmat(path)
```

Then I tried to convert into pandas dataframe. It doesn't work.
Could anyone help me please? I've read the previous posts, still no answer.

Thank you very much!

I use Matlab to read the .mat file, it's like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks again!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197449/matlab-data-file-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Thanks. But it still doesn't work when it reconstructs the columns. It looks like a dictionary  with only 1 key-value.