# Convert a .mat file into dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

As a Python beginner, I want to convert the [.mat file](https://phm-datasets.s3.amazonaws.com/NASA/5.+Battery+Data+Set.zip) into dataframe.

I could read the data with scipy.io.loadmat() but I couldn't convert the mat file into dataframe to use pandas or Numpy. I have tried some ways recommended but I haven't succeeded because the structure of the .mat file is abit different with the cases online.

```html
import pandas as pd
import scipy.io as sio

mat = sio.loadmat('B0005.mat')
print(mat)  #I could see the data inside the file 
print(type(mat)) #dict

#Now I would like to use something like but it doesn't work: 
con_list0 = [[element for element in upperElement] for upperElement in mat['Voltage_measured']]
con_list1 = [[element for element in upperElement] for upperElement in mat['Temperature_measured']]
con_list2 = [[element for element in upperElement] for upperElement in mat['Current_load']]

newData = list(zip(con_list0, con_list1,...))
columns = ['Voltage_measured', 'Current_measured','Temperature_measured','Current_load',...]

df = pd.DataFrame(newData, columns=columns)
```

Please help me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I suspect your `sio.loadmat` is referring to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html . Could you provide a snippet showing what you've tried? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matlab data file to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197449/matlab-data-file-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Thank you guys for your time.
In fact, I need to understand the structure of the data in the mat file before converting it into df. I found the code really helpful here: https://github.com/ABzry/battery_skunkworks/blob/master/nasa-battery-data-analysis.ipynb